# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException when using property file to retrieve username and password

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Code:

```
package maintestcases;  

import org.testng.annotations.Test;    
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;    
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SendMailSSL {

    //ClassLoader classLoader;
    @Test
    public void email() {


final BodyPart messageBodyPart;
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            final Properties props = new Properties();
            try {
                props.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("maintestcases/Credentials.properties"));
                String Username = props.getProperty("username");
                String Password= props.getProperty("password");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.***.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");



            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("username"),props.getProperty("password"));
                }
              });

            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);


                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("vijayalakshmi.lakshmanan@xxxx.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("vijayalakshmi.lakshmanan@xxxx.com"));
                message.setSubject("Automation Testing report");
                message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");     


                MimeBodyPart p1 = new MimeBodyPart();

                String html = "<html><head><title>" +
                        message.getSubject() +
                        "</title></head><body><h1>" +
                        message.getSubject() +
                        "</h1><p>This is a test of sending an HTML e-mail" +
                        " through Java.</body></html>";
                p1.setDescription(html);



                MimeBodyPart p2 = new MimeBodyPart();


                FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:\\Documents and Settings\\vlakshm\\workspace\\Trial\\test-output\\emailable-report.html");
                p2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                p2.setFileName(fds.getName());


                Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
                mp.addBodyPart(p1);
                mp.addBodyPart(p2);


                message.setContent(mp);
                  Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");


            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

    }
}
```

**Content in Property file:**

```
Credentials.properities file:
username:domain/username
Password:********
```

While executing below mentioned code, I'm getting error

> "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful.".

Although username and password is correct.

Comment: Usually that error means that your username or password are incorrect. Have you tried to authenticate with `username:username` instead of `username:domain/username`?

Comment: This exception also happens when you havent changed the security settings (in case of a Gmail account). The setting is "Access for less secure apps" for the recipient's email address.

Comment: LittlePanda, do u know the security settings with "smtp.office365.com" as when i changed the gmail security setting it works fine then when i tried the same code with Microsoft account, it fails. So do u know how to adjust it for "smtp.office365.com"?

Answer (score 1):

I got result when I changed the username from `domain\username` to `username` only.